# Allowing users to create their own role (For ARK Tribes)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am having issues here lol. I'm attempting to make a discord bot for an ARK: Survival Evolved community so they can make a customized role for their tribe without an admin's help. I've been at it for almost a week now. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('createtribe')
        .setDescription('Creates a custom role for you and your tribemates')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('tribename')
                .setDescription('The name of your tribe')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('rolecolor')
            .setDescription('The color you wish your role to have')
            .setRequired(true)),
   
    async execute(interaction) {
if (commandName === 'createtribe')
    guild.roles.create({name: `${tribename}`});
await interaction.reply("Your tribe has been successfully registered");

    }
}
```

I don't receive any errors but there is a line in the console labeled "replied: false"

Comment: Are you familiar with Javascript or have any prior coding experience?

Comment: I was following the guide on the discord.js website. I also have some coding experience from college.

Comment: `if (commandName === 'createtribe')` is missing curly braces and unnecessary, and `guild` is not defined. You should also include errors whenever you ask for coding help.

Comment: I don't get any console errors but there is a thing that pops up "replied=false"

Comment: Also guild was defined I just forgot to include it in my post. Apologies.

Comment: You need to embrace your logic within the if-statement, as well as handle the promise of `guild.roles.create()`. Also, you have not defined `tribename`

Comment: Wdym logic within the if-statement? Sorry kinda new here lolz.

Comment: Your if-statement is a one-liner. You need to give it a scope: `if (...) { CODE HERE }`. In your current code, `await interaction.reply("Your tribe has been successfully registered");` will always run regardless of the if-statement

Comment: **async execute(guild) {
if (commandName === 'createtribe') {
   await guild.roles.create({name: `${tribename}`})};
},**

That is my code for the role creation. If I screwed it up lmk.

Comment: Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering an option doesn't make it immediately available as a variable.

You need to get it through the interaction options object. Like so:

```
interaction.guild.roles.create({name: interaction.options.getString("tribename")});
```

I recommend reading the [Discord.JS guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin) fully.